# Finding an Expression as an Elementary Function for a Power Series

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, power-series

> Consider $$h(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(z-2)^n}{n}.$$
>   I wish to find an expression for $h$ as an elementary function.

This question has me stumped. I considered another function, $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n(z-2)^n.$$ This is much easier to express as an elementary function, as
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n(z-2)^n=(z-2)\frac{d}{dz}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (z-2)^n=\frac{z+3}{(z+2)^2}.$$ But for the function $h$, I cannot see a similar technique or a manipulation to yield such a function.

I would really appreciate a **hint**.

Comment: Hint: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Power_series

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I had not considered this. Despite this, I still can't yield an answer. I'm open to additional help if you are willing.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: formally $h'(z)=\sum (z-2)^{n-1}$. Calculate this sum and integrate. The answer is $Log (3-z)$ for $|z-2| <1$ where $Log$ is the principle branch of logarithm. You have to have some knowledge of logarithms in the complex plane to answer this question.

Comment: Does this give $-\ln|3-z|-\ln|z-2|+C$?

Comment: No, the sum of the series is not a real valued function. Please see my revised answer.

Comment: I believe I have calculated the sum incorrectly. I have that $$h(z)=\int\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (z-2)^{n-1} \ dz=\int\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (z-2)^n-\frac{1}{z-2} \ dz.$$

Answer (score 2):

Taking the convergent part of this sum and making

$$
y = z-2
$$

we have

$$
h(y) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{y^k}{k} = \int_0^y\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\zeta^kd\zeta = \int_0^y\frac{d\zeta}{1-\zeta}
$$

Comment: Why does $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{y^k}{k}=\int\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} y^k\ dy?$$

Comment: @Cesareo  I don't understand how the second line of equations works. For instance, as $$\frac{y^k}{k} =\int y^{k-1} \ dy \ \ \text{doesn't this imply that} \ \ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{y^k}{k}=\int\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}y^{k-1} \ dy?$$

Comment: @JulianAngussmith $y^0+y^1\Rightarrow\int_0^y\Rightarrow\frac{y^1}{1}+\frac{y^2}{2}$

Comment: Is a definite integral necessary for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Instead of looking at $h$, first try to calculate what $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}$$ would be.